# Why showing it Cannot resolve method 'isHeavier()' in my code?

Tags: java, methods

Here is my code:
public class Main {
Book[] listOfBooks;

```
    public Main (Book p1, Book p2, Book p3, Book p4, Book p5){
        listOfBooks = new Book[5];
        listOfBooks[0] = p1;
        listOfBooks[1] = p2;
        listOfBooks[2] = p3;
        listOfBooks[3] = p4;
        listOfBooks[4] = p5;
    }

    int z=0;
    public int compareTo() {
        if(this.listOfBooks[0].numberOfPages > this.listOfBooks[1].numberOfPages) {
            z=1;
        } else if(this.listOfBooks[0].numberOfPages == this.listOfBooks[1].numberOfPages) {
            z=0;
        } else {
            z = -1;
        }
        return z;
    }
    boolean s = true;
    public boolean isHeavier() {
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfBooks.length; i++) {
            if (listOfBooks[i].numberOfPages > 500) {
                s = true;
            } else {
                s = false;
            }
        }
        return s;
    }

    public String displayAll() {
        String x= " " + listOfBooks[0].numberOfPages + " ";
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book p1 = new Book(3, "s", 400);
        Book p2 = new Book(4, "t", 500);
        Book p3 = new Book(5, "u", 600);
        Book p4 = new Book(6, "v", 700);
        Book p5 = new Book(7, "w", 200);

        Main m1 = new Main(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5);

        System.out.println(m1.compareTo());

        System.out.println(m1.displayAll());

        System.out.println(p1.numberOfPages.isHeavier());
    }
}
public class Book {
int ISBN;
String bookTitle;
int numberOfPages;
int count;

public Book() {
    this.ISBN = 0;
    this.bookTitle = null;
    this.numberOfPages = 0;
    this.count = 0;
}

public Book(int ISBN, String bookTitle, int numberOfPages) {
    this.ISBN = ISBN;
    this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
    this.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public int getNumberOfPages() {
    return numberOfPages;
}

int z=0;
public int compareTo(int numberOfPages2) {
    if(this.numberOfPages>numberOfPages2) {
        z=1;
    } else if(this.numberOfPages == numberOfPages2) {
        z=0;
    } else {
        z = -1;
    }
    return z;
}
```

}

Why am I getting the error

> Cannot resolve method 'isHeavier()'

IntelliJ told me to rename method name but it cannot be solving.
Same problem acquires no matter what I do.
I have edited my code.
I have added book class this time.

IntelliJ told me to rename method name but it cannot be solving.
Same problem acquires no matter what I do.
I have edited my code.
I have added book class this time.

Comment: Never mind `isHeavier`... where is `numberOfPages` defined? If it's not of type `Main`, then it won't have the method `isHeavier()`

Comment: In the source you are showing, the  method isHeavier() exists on the Main class. You are trying to invoke it on the Book class. So most likely, the Book class doesnt have such a method.

Comment: So, most likely, you want `m1.isHeavier()`, not `m1.p1.isHeavier()``

Answer (score 0):

While your example lacks the `Book` implementation, it is very likely that `Book.numberOfPages()` returns an integer and not a `Book`. This has no `isHeavier()` method, only `Main` has.

Without knowing anything from your code except your example, I think the most likely fix is: change `System.out.println(p1.numberOfPages.isHeavier());` to `System.out.println(m1.isHeavier());`.